# How to save JavaScript variable on server file in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I run a server on Flask in python, I have an html page that has a slider:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="624" max="1999" value="20" class="slider" id="mySlider">
</div>
```

With the script:

```
<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");
</script>
```

I want to save the value `slider.value` in a `.txt` file on the server, and then read it again in another html file.

What is the best solution to do so?

Comment: if `<input>` is in `<form action="URL">` with `<button>` then it will send value from `<input>`  to `URL` when you click button. OR you would have to use AJAX in JavaScript to send value to URL. And then code in this URL may save it in file.

Comment: Reconsider if you should really use a text file. If you want to do reading and writing it would be a lot easier to use a database. Look into SQLite or Postgres or MySQL